# Ordenação 2 Colunas ao mesmo tempo SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte estrutura da tabela.

```
Ticket | Data | ID
```

O campo data é datetime, ticket, id e gerador são int.

O que eu preciso é que seja feita uma ordenação dos campos ticket e data ao mesmo tempo.

Resultado atual.

```
Ticket    Data/Hora     
532       06/06/2018
532       10/08/2017
532       11/07/2018
532       01/03/2016
```

Resultado esperado.

```
Ticket    Data/Hora
532       01/03/2016
532       10/08/2017
532       06/06/2018
532       11/07/2018
```

Consulta atual abaixo.

```
select  
w.service_req_id Ticket,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), w.to_time, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), w.to_time, 108) [Data/Hora],
'Interna' [Ação é Pública? (Pública/Interna)],
case when u.ref_id = '1' then '454' 
     when u.ref_id is null then ur.ref_id else u.ref_id end as Gerador,
w.description +char(13)+char(10) Descrição,
cast(w.id as varchar(100)) as Seq
from work_report w
left join sysaid_user u on u.user_name = w.user_name
left join service_req se on se.id = w.service_req_id
left join sysaid_user ur on ur.user_name = se.responsibility
where w.service_req_id in(532)
and (w.description not in('') and w.description not in ('.'))
order by 1,6
```

Observe que tentei utilizado order by pra ticket e id, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisar usar o `ORDER BY` de acordo com a prioridade:

```
ORDER BY w.service_req_id, w.to_time
```

> [`SELECT` – Cláusula `ORDER BY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Classifica dados retornados por uma consulta no `SQL Server`. Use esta cláusula para:
>
> - Classificar o conjunto de resultados de uma consulta pela lista de colunas especificada e, opcionalmente, limitar as linhas retornadas a um intervalo especificado. A ordem na qual as linhas são retornadas em um conjunto de resultados não é garantida, a menos que uma cláusula `ORDER BY` seja especificada.
> - Determine a ordem na qual os valores da [função de classificação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) serão aplicados ao conjunto de resultados.

Comment: creio ser mais seguro order by 1,2

Comment: @Motta já não funcionaria porque ordenara a data como se fosse string

Comment: O "convert" não converte para DATE ?!

Comment: @Motta não, naquele caso está convertendo para varchar. Fora que colocar a posição da coluna no order by é perigoso. Se você adicionar uma coluna antes quebra a lógica

Comment: O erro começa em armazenar data como string , começa a complicar queries que deveriam ser triviais.

Comment: @Motta sim mas isso não faz parte da pergunta